# VS running but unresponsive when placing a break point within one of my functions

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Using VS2013 and .NET 4.5, placing a breakpoint within one of my functions causes VS to crash. The application disappears, but VS is still running, but unresponsive, and must be killed. Removing the breakpoint, the application runs fine. Changing to .NET 2.0 allows me to add the break point. 
Deleting the suo file, performing the chkdsk, copying the code to another file are all the things I have tried, but do not make a difference.

Comment: is this issue with any project? If you create a new ,net 4.5 console app, does the same issue exists? Also, does it occur when your project is running (debug and/or release mode) or when you're editing the files?

Comment: Dave, thank you for responding. Unfortunately I am posting this on behalf of my brother and any answers to your questions will take time to post as it is all by mail. I hope you can continue to help. I wil get a response back to you as quickly as possible.

Comment: The issue is not with any other .NET 4.5 project. This project was fine for sometime, and has only recently decided to have this problem. I have had this problem on another bigger project some time ago, but I assumed that was somthing to do with the multi-threaded enviroment. This is a single thread project though.  The problem does not occur in Release mode ( as you can't do break points) or when running the executable or without the break points.

Comment: I have  similar in 2010.we can place a break point but if we step in/over it crashes. Are you using COM? Also does event viewer show anything?